# Possible to get all views for specific Youtube category?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I am looking to find way to pull the total view count for a specific video category like **Sports** (id - 17). Is that a possibility with the YouTube API currently? Would I need to check the statistics on each video in a category and loop through all pages and add up all the view counts for each to get that number or is there a better way?

my current code to pull the Sports category:

```
api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

# Get credentials and create an API client
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file, scopes)
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

request = youtube.search().list(
    part="snippet",
    order="viewCount",
    regionCode="US",
    type="video",
    videoCategoryId="17"
)
response = request.execute()

print(response)
```

Comment: As far as I know, the YouTube Data API does not provide the info you're needing.

Comment: as SO user stvar mentioned in his comment, YouTube Data API does not provide that info, but, I'm curious: what is your criteria for this? - I don't think all videos are categorized. Do you have a defined scope for this? - if so, please [edit] your question with more details.